# How to extract the value between the underscores from the below text by using a formula only?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

P_AGE_ABD

P_ARCHITECTURE_ABD

P_CUSTOM_ABD

P_DEVELOP_ABD

P_ENTERPRISE_ABD

Hi, I need to extract values in between the two underscores using a formula in excel. Can anyone help with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=MID(A9, FIND("_", A9, 1)+1,  FIND("_", A9, FIND("_", A9, 1)+1) - FIND("_", A9, 1) -1 )
```

Basically you find the index of first _
Find the index of next _, but start at a position after the first _
Then calculate the length
Use MID function

** REPLACE A9 with your cell reference

Comment: Thanks, this helps :)